# Using common code on on different objects

Tags: apex, class

I have a class which helps to perform a particular operation on a particular object. The code which was designed completely on contact object.

I can write new class and use the same code on another object and use that, but I don't want to duplicate the code.

How can I make the code more generic where I can use the code in different objects as well.

Below is my sample code.

```
public class ContactClass {

    public static void UserAssignment(List<Contact> contacts){

        AssignmentRulesParser parser = new AssignmentRulesParser();
        Map<Integer, String> orderToAssignmentTeamMap = new Map<Integer, String>();
        List<String> recruitersForContactsToUpdate = new List<String>();
        Boolean allowReassignUser = false;

        Map<Integer, List<String>> assignmentRules = parser.parse('Contact');

        List<Assignment_Rules__c> assignRules = [
                                    SELECT Order__c, Assignment_Team__c
                                    FROM Assignment_Rules__c
                                    WHERE sObject_API_Name__c = 'Contact'];
        system.debug('assignRules>>>'+assignRules);

        for (Assignment_Rules__c rule : assignRules) {
            orderToAssignmentTeamMap.put(Integer.valueOf(rule.Order__c), rule.Assignment_Team__c.trim());
        }

        Integer maxOrderValue = 0;
        for (Integer v_index : assignmentRules.keySet()) {
            if (maxOrderValue <= v_index) { maxOrderValue = v_index; } 
        }

        for (Contact contact : contacts) {
            for (Integer i = 0; i <= maxOrderValue; i++) {
                if (assignmentRules.containsKey(i)) {
                    for (String rule : assignmentRules.get(i)) {
                        allowReassignUser = false;
                        List<String> splittedRule = rule.trim().split(' ', 3);
                        system.debug(splittedRule[0] + 'splittedRule[0] ::');
                        system.debug(splittedRule[1] + 'splittedRule[1] ::');
                        system.debug(splittedRule[2] + 'splittedRule[2] ::');
                        if (splittedRule[1] == '==') {
                            if (Contact.get(splittedRule[0]) == splittedRule[2]) {
                                allowReassignUser = true;
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        } else if (splittedRule[1] == '!=') {
                            if (Contact.get(splittedRule[0]) != splittedRule[2]) {
                                allowReassignUser = true;
                                continue;
                            } else {
                                break; 
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    system.debug('allowReassignUser>>>'+allowReassignUser);

                    datetime timeNow = DateTime.now();

                    if (allowReassignUser) {

                        system.debug('orderToAssignmentTeamMap.get(i) ::' + orderToAssignmentTeamMap.get(i));
                        List<Config__c> recruiters = [
                                                SELECT Active_User__c, Assignment_Order__c, Group_Name__c, User__r.Id,
                                                Last_Assigned__c, No_Availability_End_Date_Time__c, Group_Name__r.Name__c,
                                                User__c,End_Time_Formula__c, Start_Time_Formula__c, 
                                                Working_Hours_End_Time__c, No_Availability_Start_Date_Time__c
                                                FROM Config__c
                                                WHERE Group_Name__r.Name__c =:orderToAssignmentTeamMap.get(i)
                                                AND Active_User__c = true
                                                ORDER BY Assignment_Order__c ASC];


                        system.debug('recruiters.size() ::' + recruiters.size());

                        Integer nextIndexToConsider = null;     
                        if(recruiters.size() == 1) {
                            if(contact.RecordTypeId == rtConType[0].Id) {
                                contact.Account_Manager__c = recruiters[0].User__r.Id;
                            } else {
                                contact.Recruiter__c = recruiters[0].User__r.Id;
                            }
                        } else if(recruiters.size() > 1) {          

                            for (Integer j = 0; j < recruiters.size(); j++) {
                                system.debug('j loop value :' + j); 
                                system.debug('recruiters[j].Last_Assigned__c ::' + recruiters[j].Last_Assigned__c);


                                if (recruiters[j].Last_Assigned__c || nextIndexToConsider != null) {
                                    system.debug('assign check  ::');
                                    datetime timeworkingHrs = DateTime.now();

                                    DateTime notAvailableStartTime = null;
                                    if(j != recruiters.size()-1) {
                                        if(recruiters[j+1].No_Availability_Start_Date_Time__c != null) {
                                            notAvailableStartTime = recruiters[j+1].No_Availability_Start_Date_Time__c;
                                        } else {
                                            notAvailableStartTime = null;
                                        }                                   
                                    } else if(recruiters[0].No_Availability_Start_Date_Time__c != null) {
                                        notAvailableStartTime = recruiters[0].No_Availability_Start_Date_Time__c;
                                    }

                                    Datetime notAvailableEndTime = null;
                                    if(j != recruiters.size()-1) {
                                        if(recruiters[j+1].No_Availability_End_Date_Time__c != null) {
                                            notAvailableEndTime = recruiters[j+1].No_Availability_End_Date_Time__c;
                                        } else {
                                            notAvailableEndTime = null;
                                        }
                                    } else if(recruiters[0].No_Availability_End_Date_Time__c != null) {
                                        notAvailableEndTime = recruiters[0].No_Availability_End_Date_Time__c;
                                    }


                                    DateTime startTime = null;
                                    if(j != recruiters.size()-1) {
                                        if(recruiters[j+1].Start_Time_Formula__c != null) {
                                            startTime = DateTime.parse(recruiters[j+1].Start_Time_Formula__c);
                                        } else {
                                            startTime = null;
                                        }                                   
                                    } else if(recruiters[0].Start_Time_Formula__c != null) {
                                        startTime = DateTime.parse(recruiters[0].Start_Time_Formula__c);
                                    }

                                    Datetime endTime = null;
                                    if(j != recruiters.size()-1) {
                                        if(recruiters[j+1].End_Time_Formula__c != null) {
                                            endTime = DateTime.parse(recruiters[j+1].End_Time_Formula__c);
                                        } else {
                                            endTime = null;
                                        }
                                    } else if(recruiters[0].End_Time_Formula__c != null) {
                                        endTime = DateTime.parse(recruiters[0].End_Time_Formula__c);
                                    }

                                    system.debug('startTime ::' + startTime);
                                    system.debug('endTime ::' + endTime);
                                    system.debug('timeworkingHrs ::' + timeworkingHrs);

                                    if(!((notAvailableStartTime != null && notAvailableStartTime < timeworkingHrs) && (notAvailableEndTime != null && notAvailableEndTime > timeworkingHrs))) {

                                        if((startTime == null || startTime < timeworkingHrs) && (endTime == null || endTime > timeworkingHrs)) {
                                            system.debug('check here ::'); 
                                            if(contact.RecordTypeId == rtConType[0].Id){
                                                system.debug('inside AM ::');
                                                contact.Account_Manager__c = (j == (recruiters.size() - 1))
                                                    ? recruiters[0].User__r.Id : recruiters[j + 1].User__r.Id;
                                            } else {
                                                system.debug('inside 1 ::');

                                                contact.Recruiter__c = (j == (recruiters.size() - 1))   
                                                    ? recruiters[0].User__r.Id : recruiters[j+1].User__r.Id;
                                                system.debug('contact.Recruiter__c ::' + contact.Recruiter__c);
                                            }

                                            break;
                                        } else {
                                            nextIndexToConsider = Math.mod((j+1), recruiters.size());
                                            j = nextIndexToConsider - 1;
                                            system.debug('nextIndexToConsider ::' + nextIndexToConsider);
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        nextIndexToConsider = Math.mod((j+1), recruiters.size());
                                        j = nextIndexToConsider - 1;
                                        system.debug('nextIndexToConsider ::' + nextIndexToConsider);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        system.debug('recruiters>>>'+recruiters);

                        for (Config__c recruiter : recruiters) {
                            if(contact.Recruiter__c != null){
                                system.debug('last assign 1 ::');
                                recruiter.Last_Assigned__c = recruiter.User__r.Id == contact.Recruiter__c;

                        }

                        system.debug('recruiters after update>>>'+recruiters);

                        update recruiters;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

If you check my code, I am performing round robin and using it to update values in a single object. But as the class is associated with contact object, I can't use it for any other object. I can use `sObject` concept to handle it but I think I can't assigned field mappings through it. 
Any ideas will be helpful to proceed on this.

Comment: Step one is simplify what you have. This code is *way to complex* to genericize.

Comment: hmm ok. but I will see if I can reduce any no of lines to make code more easy. It has so many iterations which I need to check and even I am using custom settings to fetch some reuiqred criteria and use it for my implemetation. I am looking for how I can convert the public static void UserAssignment(List<Contact> contacts){} method for dynamic object handling

Answer (score 0):

The broad answer is to make use of [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) based on information you obtain using [describe calls](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_describe_objects_understanding.htm) and to only use the methods of the base [SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm) class (put and get field values) when accessing or updating data. If your logic requires additional configuration you can make use of e.g. [custom settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_customsettings.htm) to hold that configuration.

While this might sound complicated the code doesn't have to be. For example, this code is one way to clone child objects of any type:

```
private static void cloneChildren(
        SObjectType type,
        SObjectField parentField,
        Id oldParentId,
        Id newParentId,
        SObject[] oldChildren,
        SObject[] newChildren
        ) {
    List<String> fields = new List<String>(type.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet());
    for (SObject sob : Database.query(''
            + ' select ' + String.join(fields, ',')
            + ' from ' + String.valueOf(type)
            + ' where ' + String.valueOf(parentField) + ' = :oldParentId'
            )) {
        SObject clone = sob.clone();
        clone.put(parentField, newParentId);
        oldChildren.add(sob);
        newChildren.add(clone);     
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

created a new class and a new method where I can dynamically query though Sobject and its related fields. Below is some sample code which I have used. 
Also, executing all this flow through a process builder

> Apex code:

public static List getRecords(String objName,List recIds) {

```
    Map<String,Schema.SObjectType> gd = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
    Schema.SObjectType sobjType = gd.get(objName);


    //Schema.sObjectType sObjectTypeVar = objName.sObjectType;
    DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = sobjType.getDescribe();

    List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>( describeResult.fields.getMap().keySet() );

    String query =
      ' SELECT ' +
          String.join( fieldNames, ',' ) +
      ' FROM ' +
          describeResult.getName() + 
      ' WHERE Id = ' + '\'' + recIds.get(0) + '\'';

  System.debug('query : '+query );

    // return generic list of sobjects or typecast to expected type
    List<SObject> records = Database.query( query );        
    System.debug( records );
    return records;
}

public class RecordDetails {
    @InvocableVariable
    public List<String> ids;

    @InvocableVariable
    public String ObjectName;

    @InvocableVariable
    public List<String> recordTypes;

    @InvocableVariable
    public String fieldToBeUpdated;

}
```